# How to restore Reliable Service state from existing backup?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a Stateful Service with backup logic implemented according to [the corresponding documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-backup-restore/)

Just like so:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // ...

  while (true)
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    BackupDescription myBackupDescription = new BackupDescription(BackupOption.Full, this.BackupCallbackAsync);
    await this.BackupAsync(myBackupDescription);

    // ...

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
  }
}

private async Task<bool> BackupCallbackAsync(BackupInfo backupInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var backupId = Guid.NewGuid();
  // backup files copied to external storage here ...
  return true;
}
```

Documentation suggests only one way to restore backups - with `OnDataLossAsync` method. But I cannot provoke an invocation of this mehtod.

So, the question is: how may I restore the service state from my backup in case of full data loss?

For example, all the service fabric cluster nodes have been destroyed. The only thing I have is my backup. What should I do after redeployment to restore my services' state?

I checked `Data` and `Log` directories of Service Fabric cluster manager, but data format seems to be different comparing to the backup.

Comment: Did you read the chapter 'Deleted or lost service'? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt693569.aspx it seems to describe what you're after..

Comment: I did read about this method. As far as I can understand, it's intended for test purposes and should not be used in production environment: "
It is not recommended to use FabricClient.ServiceManager.InvokeDataLossAsync on each partition to restore the entire service, since that may corrupt your cluster state."

Comment: That's a different method from `FabricClient.TestManagementClient.StartPartitionDataLossAsync`
(I do agree that it's unclear..)

Comment: Probably it's the answer. Will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dataloss can be triggered for a service with something like the following code:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
$s = "fabric:/WebReferenceApplication/InventoryService"
$p = Get-ServiceFabricApplication | Get-ServiceFabricService -ServiceName $s | Get-ServiceFabricPartition | Select -First 1
$p | Invoke-ServiceFabricPartitionDataLoss -DataLossMode FullDataLoss -ServiceName $s
```

There's an example that shows how backup and restore works in the [web reference sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/), and the specific code is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/blob/df74b6cd17a56cfb7a952118a0da2f9c539c668b/ReferenceApp/Inventory.Service/InventoryService.cs#L310-L315).

The full docs for backup and restore are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-backup-restore).